# How to Lock screen orientation when displaying reverse landscape in android?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

im trying to Lock screen `orientation` in android application.I used following code to lock screen orientation when specific button click fire.

```
// Inside button click

Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
 if (display.getOrientation() == 1) {
                   setRequestedOrientation(0);
 } else if (display.getOrientation() == 0) {
                   setRequestedOrientation(1);
 } else if (display.getOrientation() == 3) {
                   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
 }
```

Above code working for both landscape and portrait screen orientations but its not working for reverse landscape mode.In that case always my activity change it's `orientation` to default `landscape` mode.Also i notice,when device in reverse landscape mode , `display.getOrientation()` always return 3.
**How can i find solution for this problem?**

Answer (score 15):

I've been dealing with the same problem using API 8. Looks like while in reserseLandscape mode, if you call

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Android will return 2 (SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER), which won't lock the orientation at all. In fact the constant SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE is not even defined for the ActivityInfo class, even though the value actually exists. 
For my app I ended up creating this method:

```
public void lockScreenOrientation() {
    switch (((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
        .getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_90: 
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180: 
        setRequestedOrientation(9/* reversePortait */); 
        break;          
    case Surface.ROTATION_270: 
        setRequestedOrientation(8/* reverseLandscape */); 
        break;
    default : 
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
    }
}
```

I call this method whenever I need to lock the orientation, and then I can simply release it calling

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice one! Considering the number of threads asking for orientation locking, I'm surprised you don't have tens of upvotes.

Comment: @tricknology Note this is an old trick for API 8. What API are you using and what error are you getting?

Comment: @autremoi, API 11+  The UI just hands. No FC or ANR but I can't click anything.  The answer I posted works for me though.

Comment: when do you set it to unspecified?

Comment: when do you call setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED); ?

Answer (score 3):

```
public void lockScreenOrientation() {
    switch (((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
        .getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_90: 
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180: 
        setRequestedOrientation(9/* reversePortait */); 
        break;          
    case Surface.ROTATION_270: 
        setRequestedOrientation(8/* reverseLandscape */); 
        break;
    default : 
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
    }
}
```

The answer of autremoi worked for me, I created a new answer because my reputation does not let me vote him up yet.

The only difference in my code is that I recover the sensor with this other one

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

Comment: when do you recover the sensor?

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest file, just simply type in the following codes:

```
        android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
```

example:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.gaspar.slinfilipino.Quiz"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_quiz"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
        android:parentActivityName="com.gaspar.slinfilipino.SignLanguageMenu" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.gaspar.slinfilipino.SignLanguageMenu" />
    </activity>
```

It works on me. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tried autremoi's answer but it killed my UI. I found an answer that does work, however I found that a mix of this: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/programmatically-locking-android-screen-orientation

and this: [getSize() giving me errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654016/getsize-giving-me-errors) works, and should on all Android versions.

Use it with `setRequestedOrientation(lockOrientation());`

Happy coding!

```
private int lockOrientation(){
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int rotation = display.getRotation();

    Point size = new Point();
    size.x = display.getWidth();
    size.y = display.getHeight();

    int lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
        // if rotation is 0 or 180 and width is greater than height, we have
        // a tablet
        if (size.x > size.y) {
            if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            } else {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
            }
        } else {
            // we have a phone
            if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            } else {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // if rotation is 90 or 270 and width is greater than height, we
        // have a phone
        if (size.x > size.y) {
            if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            } else {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
            }
        } else {
            // we have a tablet
            if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
            } else {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            }
        }
    }
    return lock;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

hi if u want lock screen orientation u have to set manifest file

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent">
```

Comment: Thanx.But i need to  do in run time.Also i  want to overrite onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() method for service bind.

Comment: Actually i want to lock screen orientation when specific button click fire.So i dnt want to add entry to manifest.Other thing is my above code working fine for both landscape and portrait screens.Issue is occurs only screen in reverse landscape mode.In that mode screen is always change its orientation to default landscape mode.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

if u want portrait

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: Yes. I knw this.But i want to lock screen when my screen in Reverse landcape mode.Do you knw there is orientation mode called REVERSE_LANDSCAPE?