# customization of List view by extending base adapter class

Tags: android

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int btnHt = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()
                / numberOfRows;
        int btnWdth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()
                / numberOfColumns;
```

I get warning that get Height is deprecated method how to get rid of it??

I did suppress but was of no use...!

I want the code of extending base adapter in order to get customized color to List View

Comment: @hirshi read this link http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
public void getSize (Point outSize)
```

Like this [getSize() giving me errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654016/getsize-giving-me-errors)