# Gallery doesn't show anything when it has only 1 image

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-gallery

I'm using `SurfaceView` in my 1st activity. On clicking an image using `SurfaceView`, I move to 2nd activity also storing path of the recently clicked image. In 2nd activity, I want to display that image in `Gallery`.

In 2nd activity on a button click, again I move to 1st activity and after clicking picture, I move to 2nd activity.

Now in 2nd activity, there will 2 images that should be displayed in `Gallery`.

My problem is after clicking 1st image, `Gallery` is not displaying anything. Note that `getView()` of adapter set for `Gallery` is getting called.

But after clicking 2nd image onwards, when there are 2 or more images in `Gallery`, they are getting displayed.

I also tried `g.refreshDrawableState();` after

```
g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
g.setOnItemClickListener(this);     
g.setSelection(0, false);
```

but to no avail.

I know what I have written here sounds complex, but try to visualize the scenario.

Any help appreciated.

### Edit

**ImageAdapter.java**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImageIds.length;//mImageIds is Array of image paths
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

            final String imageUri = mImageIds[position].trim();
            try {
                if (imageUri.length() != 0) {
                    File f = new File(imageUri);
                    if (f.exists()) {
                        b = constants.shrinkBitmap(f.getPath(), 800, 800);
                        d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
                        i.setImageDrawable(d);
                    } else {
                        i.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    }
                } else {
                    i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
//BELOW "length" is some predefined value
            i.setPadding(Math.round(length * 0.05f), 0,
                    Math.round(length * 0.05f), 0);
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(Math
                    .round(length * 0.9f),
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            i.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            return i;
        }
    }
```

### Edit (2)

After **Vikram**'s suggestion, I tried logging *length* value and it was indeed **0** for the first time i.e. when calling `i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(Math.round(length * 0.9f),LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

I set this `length` variable just after `onCreate()` by this way:

```
g.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
       length = g.getRight() - g.getLeft();
     }
    });
```

as I want to retrieve width of my parent layout in code and accordingly set Gallery item width.

I know the reason I get `length` as 0 is `setContentView()` takes bit of time to take effect. How can I retrieve before Adapter is called?

Comment: Can you post your adapter code?

Comment: In case of the 1st image click, check the contents of `mImageIds` using Logcat. Do this in `getView()`. Your adapter looks okay to me.

Comment: `mImageIds` do have image URI's. Also `g.getChildCount` also gives 0+ result.

Comment: Double check the value of `length`. It might be set to `zero` for the first item.

Comment: Oh gosh. How did I missed that. Please check my edited question.

Comment: How about you set `length` to the screen width? Or, you can call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` from inside the `run()` method, after computing `length`. You will need to initialize your `myAdapter` variable before calling `g.post()`.

Comment: Done that and it solved the issue. But it generates the the issue that is layout is loaded WITHOUT gallery item first. then it blinks and gallery is populated. I solved it by setting visibility to invisible initially and only after populating gallery, display the whole layout.

Comment: Just integrate all your comments and post as answer. I'll accept it. And by the way, thanks a ton ! cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `length` seems to be the problem here. If it's value is `zero`, when `getView()` for the first item is called, the `width` parameter is set to `zero`.

In your edit, `length` is indeed getting a non-zero value, perhaps a bit late. You can make the following call to update the view:

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This call should be placed inside `run()` after the computation of `length`.

Your workaround for the 'blinking' is fine. As an alternative(and if the gallery's width should match screen width), try this:

In place of:

```
g.post(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
   length = g.getRight() - g.getLeft();
 }
});
```

put:

```
Point pointSize = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(pointSize);
length = pointSize.x;
```

Place this before initializing the adapter.

Another thing to note here is that `g.getRight()` is computed as:

```
g.getRight() = g.getLeft() + g.getWidth()
```

So, to compute `length`, you may as well do:

```
length = g.getWidth()
```

as:

```
getWidth() = getRight() - getLeft()
```

Comment: For `Point` funda, I get *The method getSize(Point) is undefined for the type Display* error.

Comment: So I used accepted answer of [this que.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654016/getsize-giving-me-errors)