# Method getSize(Point) is undefined for the type Display

Tags: android, eclipse, width, screen-size

I'm writing an App for Android.
I want to gather the screen width during runtime dynamically to draw the dialogs depending on the display size. For that I wrote the following function:

```
public static int getDisplayWidth( Context context )
{
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = 0;
    if( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13 )
    {
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size); //Error
        width = size.x;
    }
    else
    {
        width = display.getWidth();
    }
    return width;
}
```

But I get an error on line "display.getSize(size);"

Error: "The method getSize(Point) is undefined for the type Display"

I use Ecslipe as Development Environment.

Project Build Target is "Android 2.3.3".
In Manifest.xml I set: 
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />`

Can anybody tell me why I get this error?
What have I done wrong?

Sapp

Comment: Do not build with 2.3.3 (API 10) but with newest 18 and test it on 2.3.3 device

Comment: I build it with 4.2.2 and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Older Android versions don't have the getSize() method. The error is either calling, or linking, to the absent function.

```
private static Point getDisplaySize(final Display display) {
    final Point point = new Point();
    try {
        display.getSize(point);
    } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) { // Older device
        point.x = display.getWidth();
        point.y = display.getHeight();
    }
    return point;
}
```

Experiment with the try-catch & see if this helps. This should safely fallback to the older API & ensure your code works on the broad range of devices.

Really, a bit of a balls-up on Google's part.

See:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html
- [getSize() giving me errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654016/getsize-giving-me-errors)

Comment: Not if it's necessary to fallback to working functionality, @Selvin. Granted, with a stable API, you shouldn't need this kind of hokum. But better to have a working application, than a nice "theory".

Comment: Working functionality should looks like: CompatHelper interface with getDisplaySize(final Display display) method... Two implementation OlderHelper and PostHoneyHelper and implementation chooser based on Build.VERSION.SDK_INT... This should be builded with highest API. Then you shouldn't be worry about compile and runtime errors... Just like it is done in support lib :-)