# Android java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.Display.getSize

Tags: java, android

I'm getting this error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.Display.getSize`

How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
Point p = new Point();
this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(p);
int screenWidth = p.x;
int screenHeight = p.y;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [getSize() giving me errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654016/getsize-giving-me-errors)

Answer (score 0):

getSize() method was added in API level 13. May be you are running your app on device with lower version than 13. Can you please validate this.

Answer (score 0):

if you develop for API 12 or lower:

```
int screenWidth = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth;
int screenHeight = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight;
```

if you develop for api 13 or higher
Maybe you should install the right SDK (in eclipse Windows > Android SDK Manager)