# Rectangle not appearing on the right

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I'm trying to create a rectangle within a canvas so that it appears on the right hand side of the screen but the app seems to crash every time I run it. I seriously don't know am I doing wrong here + what needs to change within my code?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.apptacularapps.customview.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/diagram"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DrawView drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        setContentView(drawView);
    }
}
```

**DrawView.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Context context;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        //Code to Measure the Screen width in pixels

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;

        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 5, canvas.getHeight(), paint );

        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(canvas.getWidth()-width, 0, 5, canvas.getHeight(), paint );
    }
}
```

Comment: Crash? Post your logcat please, I forgot my crystal ball this morning...

Comment: Why do we need screen shots of your development environment and stopped message?

Comment: Why ask a question like that anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My earlier answer was because of my lack of understanding of your problem. Sorry for the inconvenience caused, if any. I am not sure if i can help you, but try this.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    //Code to Measure the Screen width in pixels

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 5, canvas.getHeight(), paint );

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawRect(canvas.getWidth()-width, 0, 5, canvas.getHeight(), paint );
}
```

In the above piece of code, in the last line, instead of `canvas.getWidth()-width`, type `canvas.getWidth()-(float) width`. Because width is `integer` and canvas.getWidth() returns `float` and float-int returns a recurring floating number.

Check the value of `width`. Is it as expected ? Also try setting the value width manually and see if the problem persists.

Hope this helps and solves the trouble !

Have a look at [this question and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654016/getsize-giving-me-errors).

Comment: What should be there regarding that and why?

Comment: My rectangles are being defined in java not xml

Comment: My rectangle is only 5dp in width (as stated in my code)

Comment: It doesn't work. All I'm left with is this: (check the latest emulator screenshot)

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is this (the image under **Final desired result**) and so if you think there is a better / more efficient way of doing this then please let me know. Many thanks. :-)

Comment: Have you tried `(float) (canvas.getWidth()-width)` ? If yes, then sorry. I cannot help further.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<com.example.mystackoverflow.MyView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

MyView class

```
public class MyView extends View {

private Paint mPaint;
private int view_width, view_height;

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(color.Red));
    mPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //canvas.drawRect(0, 0, view_width, view_height, mPaint);
      canvas.drawRect(view_width/2, 0, view_width, view_height, mPaint);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    view_width = right - left;
    view_height = bottom - top;
}
```

}

Comment: Nope. My rectangle needs to be 5 pixels wide so using view width will not help + I want the width and height of my view to stay the same + the colour to remain the same also.

Comment: I don't want to change any of that Komal. All I want is for the rectangle to be drawn on the right. `paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 5, canvas.getHeight(), paint );` This code draws it on the left so obviously something here needs to change. What about the first number on the left? After all, it represents pixels from the left.

Comment: how much width you want..... have you tried my code. oncetry it you can change myview in the layout as according to ur requirement. In the onLayout i am calculating the view width and height from xml layout...

Comment: I want the rectangle to have a width of 5 and I want my view to have the width of the screen (`fill_parent`). I will be adding more shapes later on.

Comment: Don't forget to make the pixel independent from resolution. See DisplayMetrics for additional information.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is this (the image under **Final desired result**) and so if you think there is a better / more efficient way of doing this then please let me know. Many thanks. :-)

Comment: i have done changes in ondraw() and in XML file once try the updated code                                      canvas.drawRect(view_width/2, 0, view_width, view_height, mPaint);  in xml:    android:layout_width="match_parent"