# why getHeight() or getWidth() not work in Android Studio

Tags: android-fragments

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
if(d.getWidth()>d.getHeight()){

}
```

Why `getWidth()` not work? :(

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654016/getsize-giving-me-errors

Answer (score 2):

getHeight() and getWidth() was deprecated in API level 13. Use `getSize(Point)` instead.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getHeight() and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getWidth()

try

```
WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

Point point = new Point();
d.getSize(point);
if( d.x > d.y ) {
}
```