# Android: How to stick to the same orientation the Activity started with

Tags: android, android-activity

I know how to lock an activity in a specific orientation (in *AndroidManifest.xml*):

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape|portrait"
```

I know how to lock to a specific orientation programmatically:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
```

But, how do I lock the activity to the orientation in which started at? e.g., if it started portrait, it should stick to that.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean if the user holds the phone in portrait mode, the app should start in portrait mode? I think it already does that by default...

Comment: I have face same problem. Please give me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
switch (((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()) {
  case Surface.ROTATION_90:
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    break;
  case Surface.ROTATION_180:
    setRequestedOrientation(9/* reversePortait */);
    break;
  case Surface.ROTATION_270:
    setRequestedOrientation(8/* reverseLandscape */);
    break;
  default :
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9319860/1324235).

Answer (score 5):

Use `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` when your app starts, then programmatically set the orientation like you do above. The method will return either  `ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` or  `ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`

Comment: This is almost complete, the problem is that there are _two_ landscape: _SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_ and _SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE_. The same for portrait. So, since `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` return only portrait or landscape (but not reverse), I might get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i do it:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in the activity in the manifest

Comment: This is not good: the orientation will be **always** portrait. I want it to stick to the orientation the Activity started at, which may be landscape.