# Android stick application run in always landscape mode

Tags: android, android-orientation

I have develop one application, I am set my  application run in portrait mode.
But in android stick any application run in landscape mode.

Is there any way to run my application in portrait mode.

I have tried all app from play store whose functionality is change screen orientation.
But not working in android stick.

Please help!!!

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Clear it.

Comment: Step #1: Find the customer service contact information for the manufacturer of this "android stick". Step #2: Ask customer service your question. Nobody else can help you.

Comment: What is an "android stick"?

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282683/android-how-to-stick-to-the-same-orientation-the-activity-started-with

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly because your question is not really clear.

Anyways, you can **force portrait or landscape mode** in your `Activity's` `onCreate(...)` method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // force portrait mode
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

       // other stuff...
    }
```