# How do I make android activity orientation stick to starting value?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-orientation, device-orientation, screen-rotation

Before we start, this is not a duplicate of this older question: [Android: How to stick to the same orientation the Activity started with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282683/android-how-to-stick-to-the-same-orientation-the-activity-started-with), my use case is a little more specific and new options became available since the other question was asked and answered

I have a 'view image' screen within my app. The screen works in either orientation, but should not change during viewing an image:

- If I have the phone `portrait` and open the view screen, the image should be displayed `portrait`
- If I then rotate the phone to `landscape`, the image should still be displayed `portrait`
- If I exit and reenter the screen with the phone in `landscape`, the image should be displayed `landscape`
- If I exit, rotate the phone to`portrait` and reenter the screen, the image should be displayed `portrait` once again

In other words, I want the screen to support both portrait and landscape, but only whichever was active when I opened the activity for that image. I do not want to be updated with config changes while viewing.

I have tried the new values `nosensor` and `locked` but both of these hardcode the value to 0 degrees and I cannot see an implementation difference. I don't believe I can check the orientation programmatically within the activity/fragment lifecycle because this happens after everything has been torn down and recreated. I need a solution for the manifest - does such a setting exist? Or a way to do it programmatically whilst avoiding recreating/redrawing my view without retaining instance?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve that with `Manifest` something like this

```
<activity android:name=".FirstActivity" android:screenOrientation="user">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".SecondActivity" android:screenOrientation="locked">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.View" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Source: [activity-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element), section `android:screenOrientation`

> "locked"  Locks the orientation to its current rotation, whatever that is. Added in API level 18.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a whirl later in case I was wrong, but I tried locked before and it was locking to 0 degrees (maybe locking to state when APP was launched), not locking to current state when ACTIVITY was launched. Worth a second look anyway

Comment: This works! and should be accepted as the correct answer.